# Abstract videos for sound design practice 

Tags: sound-design, video, royalty-free, download

Hi everyone,

I am looking for some video content (preferably short abstract pieces) to put some sound/music to for my portfolio and for practice. Does anyone know of any on-line resources where one might find free video content (royalty-free)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, but if you use is just for portfolio purposes I dont think you need to worry about royalties (unless you are using famous clips and representing yourself as having worked on the actual project itself).

dr

Comment: Thanks David!  I was just more curious if there existed any online sources for stock video material.  Or is it best to just scour pages like Vimeo?



Comment: Waves sponsors a sound design competition where they provide video (and audio as well).  Even if you didnt want to actuall enter, you could snag the video and work on it.